# Font makes dashes collide with text

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, extrafont

When I change the font to LM Roman 10 in a ggplot, it makes the dashes collide with the letters. How do I fix this, while still using this font?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  echo = FALSE, 
  message=FALSE, 
  warning=FALSE
)
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)

df <- data.frame(
   x = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1.5),
   y = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1.5),
   text = c("bottom-left", "top-left", "bottom-right", "top-right", "label-with-dash")
)
```


```{r test1, echo=FALSE, out.width = '80%'}
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
geom_text(aes(label = text))
```

```{r test2, echo=FALSE, out.width = '80%'}
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
geom_text(aes(label = text), family="LM Roman 10") 
```
````

Here is the result of the code above:

[image: result of code]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by making a function that replaces the dashes with unicode dashes:

```
fixl <- function(x){
  return(gsub("-", "\u00ad", x, fixed=TRUE))
}
```

that can then by applied to the plot like:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = fixl(text)), family="LM Roman 10") + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5,5), labels=fixl) + 
  theme(text = element_text(size=10, family="LM Roman 10"))
p
```

[image: result]

Comment: Would be great to have a more general solution though....